# Load data to redis during docker-compose build

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I have an application started by docker-compose. In the application I have a redis instance, configured in persistent mode. During `docker-compose build` I need to load data into redis instance. I have a lua-script that build and insert data into redis. But I don't understand how run redis and upload data using my lua-script during `docker-compose build`. I try something like:

```
FROM redis:5
...
RUN redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
RUN dataBuilder.lua
...
CMD ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf", "--appendonly yes"]
```

But `docker-compose build` stop after `RUN redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf`

How to start redis and upload data in to it during `docker-compose build`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `./dataBuilder.lua` & `redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf` command in ENTRYPOINT. Basically,

- Run the server in background
- Load the LUA file
- Once the LUA command returns exit code 0, run the redis server in Foreground else exit.

Comment: If I put dataBuilder.lua to ENTRYPOINT, it starts after docker-compose build. But I need it during docker-compose build.